# How to take in the elements of a list of unknown length as parameters for function? Python

Tags: python

I would like to be able to take a list of **unknown length** in for function parameters like this:

With a list `lis = [1, 2, 3, ...]` and a function `def func(a, b, c, ...): ...`
the elements of the list go into the function as individual parameters, `func(1, 2, 3, ...)` *not `func([1, 2, 3, ...])`

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, what is your function going to do?

Comment: I have an object that takes in a function and parameters for the function as a list, so I don't know how many parameters there are going to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use * to connote many:

```
def func(*a):
    for value in a:
        print(value)

func(1,2,3)

func(1,2,3,4,5)
```

To input many items into this function from a list:

```
my_list = [i for i in range(20)]
func(*my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*args` will give you all function parameters as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists):

```
def func(*a):
    a = list(a)
    print(a)

func(1,2,3)
func(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Or you can use it like this:

```
mylist = [i for i in range(10)]
func(*mylist)
```